# Native PHP support in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there any truth to the rumor that Visual Studio 2010 will natively support PHP coding?

(http://www.codeplex.com/php4vs)

If not,what are the options?(except VS.php)

Comment: What do you mean by options? If it's not supported, there are plenty of other IDEs that do...

Comment: Why would you want to use VS for PHP development in the first place? Not that it's not possible, but given the number of existing quality PHP IDEs, it sounds like a very strange request to me. Unless you're doing some kind of PHP/.NET integration (ugh!).

Comment: I use pdt and old zend 5.5 before, however love Visual Studio around C# and want to check if "rumor" is true

Comment: Have a look at Phalanger (http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php), though that's for VS2008 for now.

Comment: "Phalanger also allows you to use PHP as a language for writing ASP.NET applications" - I only want to benefit from vs editor for pure php code.MS already invest a lot making php more "at home" (example is http://php.iis.net/) But this drive me off topic
Will dig more about Phalanger, thanks pavel

Comment: direct link to the PHP integration (http://www.devsense.com/services/phalanger-tools) - it is Visual Studio 2010 integration provided as a part of Phalanger project, that brings PHP to .NET platform.

Comment: There is following PHP integration for Visual Studio http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 won't have native PHP support. However, it's "relatively easy" to add some language support to Visual Studio 2010. If all you want is syntax highlighting, auto comment/uncomment, and brace matching, it could be done in one sitting by someone who knows how the new extensibility model works.

After you wrote this post, I started making an add-in to show you what I mean. I downloaded the WordPress source only to note that the .php extension is registered with Expression Web 3, which does support PHP (first image).

My 15 minute attempt at an extension (second image) is not as impressive, but keep in mind I *started* working on it after I answered this question. **Edit:** Updated to color keywords/global functions/global objects separately.

[image: Microsoft Expression Web for PHP]
<sub>(source: [280z28.org](http://www.280z28.org/images/vsx/ExpressionWebForPhp.png))</sub>

[image: My PHP extension for Visual Studio 2010]
<sub>(source: [280z28.org](http://www.280z28.org/images/vsx/Vs10SamplePhp2.png))</sub>

Comment: IntelliSense is a whole different game - extremely difficult to say the least.

Comment: I think it looks good. Is there a chance that you could publish the code?

Comment: @Markus Johnsson: I haven't published the code, but I recently put an updated version of this on the Visual Studio Gallery: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2a10ba81-26c5-47d9-939b-6bcc7bbec251

Answer (score 14):

Check out [CodeLobster](http://www.codelobster.com/) php, it's free and has a very similar look and feel to visual studio plus it has IntelliSense and debugging support.

Comment: Crashed on me multiple times in the first 30 minutes, uninstalled. It's a shame, it seemed promising. Back to NotePad++ for me.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5) - new PHP integration for VS2010 and VS11.

- syntax highlighting[image: PHP syntax highlighting]
- IntelliSense (tooltip, function assist, code completion, go to definition,...)[image: intellisense here]
- code navigation
- custom file extensions
- integrated documentation

Its basic features are free, it is fast and stable (preferred for me)

Comment: its bit heavy cost wise, and not suitable if someone has 10+ php developers. and all wants to use this. this extension itself costs 10% of visual studio. something like this should be available cheaper. which will allow smaller companies like us could buy some more licenses.

Answer (score 5):

As far as large projects, VS.Php 2.7 improved quite a bit in handling large projects (10000+ files)

Give it a try and let me know,

Juan

[www.jcxsoftware.com](http://www.jcxsoftware.com)

Comment: I love VS.PHP I use it for all of my windows based development.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that VS 2010 will natively support Php.

AFAIK the only options are vs.php and vs.php. ;)

Comment: from my experience, vs.php is not an option either :(

Comment: vs.php works for small projects, but acts funny and buggy with large project It can be just me, but still is better when there is more then one choice

Comment: I would recommend looking at the latest version - 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

One of my projects has over 30,000 files, that includes however images and other items, in total about 12,000 php and js scripts, VS.php looked at it and barfed.  Back to netbeans for now.  Netbeans is amazing in what it does including the js support but I HATE java based apps.  They are way too slow and fat.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has various types of support for PHP through the links, tools, and projects listed here but not "native" support (meaning install just Visual Studio and be able to create PHP projectsa and websites).

[WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), another Microsoft product (free) does have native support. You can install it via the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and immediately start building PHP sites from scratch or install various PHP 3rd party solutions like WordPress, Drupal, etc.

WebMatrix also has pretty good support for MySQL (via the MySQL->Net connector, installable through the web platform installer, just search for MySQL in the Web PI tool). You cannot create new databases from within WebMatrix but you can create and edit tables and data once the database is created (just create the database through the mysql.exe command line).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP tools for Visual Studio:

[PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5)

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for true php projects whether small or large is "Zend Studio".

Comment: I tried 7.0, but it is heavy and slow.
Which is normal since is build over eclipse platform.
Visual Studio is lighting fast compared to Zend Studio.

Comment: Big slow and expensive. I've already invested in Visual Studio and gladly paid $99 for a copy of VS.PHP (http://www.jcxsoftware.com) which is a BIG improvement over older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Komodo, they have both free and commercial IDE

Comment: Cheaper to buy VS.PHP as an add-on to VS than buy (and learn) a whole new IDE.

Answer (score 0):

komodo is the best multi platform free version out there...

Answer (score 0):

phpDesigner7 was the best solution for PHP

Answer (score 0):

There is [PHP Language Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2a10ba81-26c5-47d9-939b-6bcc7bbec251), created by [Sam Harwell](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Sam%20Harwell). It has basic editing features for the PHP scripting language.

According to it's Visual Studio Gallery page, current editing features include:

> - Syntax highlighting, including support for HTML code outside PHP tags and within documentation comments
> - Outlining support for quickly collapsing classes and functions
> - Dropdown bars listing classes and functions within the current document
>     This extension has a relatively small feature set, but it's quite fast and usable. It was created as part of an experiment to provide editor features for multiple languages within a single document (PHP, HTML, and formatted documentation comments).

Answer (score -1):

You could use Dreamweaver. It has codehinting, dynamic error detection in code, support for most languages used on the web, support for css, html5 etc.