# How to use Visual Studio for WordPress development?

Tags: php, visual-studio, wordpress

Does anyone use Visual Studio to do WordPress development? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Background: I'm using this as an adjunct to this Pro Webmasters question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/what-resources-are-available-to-get-an-experienced-net-developer-up-and-running

Comment: I am just embarking on the same quest and it's now Jan 2017!  There is good support for PHP in VS now. I have no idea how to build a plugin for WP but I intend to learn. First stop is to install the trial version of PHP Tools for VS: https://www.devsense.com/.  I'll update with an answer once I have worked out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No built-in support for VS, and I guess there won't be, but there are some options like the answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911254/native-php-support-in-visual-studio-2010) for Expressions. The other thing I've been looking at recently is [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) - it looks promising in that it supports WordPress.

Comment: From MS Webmatrix site:
Announcement: WebMatrix formal support ends on November 1st, 2017

Answer (score 5):

Programming for Wordpress is mainly coding css, php, html and js files. If you're asking about using Visual Studio for this scenario, I'm assuming you want a plugin that provides **code hints** for WordPress development API. Since I don't know anyone, I'm going to give you some other options.

[Dreamweaver and CodeLobster come to mind as commercial applications](http://blogdesignstudio.com/web-design/best-ide-for-wordpress/). If you want something in the open source world, I recommend you a normal multi language IDE that supports PHP: the most important thing here is to use one that at least supports some kind of snippet functionality.

That goes from [Netbeans](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/screancast_about_netbeans_php_ide) to [Aptana](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/About_Aptana_Snippets) (which is based on Eclipse) to [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with [snippets functionality](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Code_Snippets). The last one is an interesting solution since it's really lightweight but you will need to create your own snippets for Wordpress API functions and hooks.

I had Aptana installed in my machine in the past, but now I'm using gVim with snipmate plugin and some snippets of my own that I create when I realize I'm doing repetitive tasks.

Comment: Perhaps I should create a new question. The critical feature for me would be the Solution Explorer; it would help to be able to open a WordPress site as a project and have all the relevant files in the Solution Explorer. I need to get more experience with WordPress first before asking about that.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked in vain for a decent plug-in for VS that would properly handle PHP, and have never been able to find one.

I always end up back with [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Did you check out [VS.php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) ?

Comment: I tried this last year and was deeply disappointed.  If you want intellisense between projects you need to import *every* php file from the external project, *one at a time*.  And I never could get debugging to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

[Textmate](http://macromates.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know. But if I came looking, someone else probably will as well. :)

[Couple of videos here about the plug-in](https://closte.com/blog/visual-studio-powerful-ide-for-wordpress-development)

[PHP Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.devsense.com/en?__c=1)

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A wordpress plugin developer saying how he uses visual studio code with plugins to run his wordpress:

https://deliciousbrains.com/vs-code-wordpress/

He seems like he knows what he's talking about.