# PHP intellisense on Visual Studio - Is it possible?

Tags: php, visual-studio

Nothing compares to Visual Studio. Infact it is the reason why I develop using Asp.Net. But once in a while I encounter a client who specifically wants a solution authored in PHP.

All PHP IDEs(Free) I have used lack a vital feature available in Visual Studio that I love so much - INTELLISENSE. So is there a free way to enable PHP intellisense on Visual Studio ?

Comment: Have you tried NetBeans? It's free, quite popular and does have intellisense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911254/native-php-support-in-visual-studio-2010 and http://www.jcxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can use VS.PHP to get php in similar VS environment.](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) (Commercial)

> Introducing the next generation of PHP
>   development tool Rich intellisense and
>   debugging support Easy to get started
>   with built-in PHP web server

**Or Free alternative:**

[Php4VS](http://php4vs.codeplex.com/)

> The Php4VS is a Package for Visual
>   studio which aims to do the same thing
>   as some others do, but with one
>   difference : for FREE !

Comment: $99.99 seems a bit steep though...?

Comment: @Martin Bean: Possibly, posted the free *possible* alternative :)

Comment: Php4VS is dead for some time :/ and Vs.PHP seams to mess up my VS environment :(

Answer (score 3):

Use Netbeans as an "extension".
1. install netbeans
2. In visual studio, right-click on a php file and select open with.  Add new.., and select Netbeans.exe in the bin folder in the Netbeans installation folder.  Click OK and also set as default.

Now, just for php files, they'll open in netbeans.  It's probably the best solution for now especially with the Express editions which don't allow 3rd party extensions.

Note: you most likely want to set netbeans to use utf-8 so you won't have problems including php files in other files.  to do that:

Go to "etc" folder in Netbeans Installatin folder. Open netbeans.conf file and add on netbeans_default_options following line:

-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

What about [PHP tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5)?

Comment: PHP Tools for Visual Studio exceeded my expectations!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not natively support PHP as a language.  However there do appear to be third party which provide extensions for PHP that provide intellisense (among other features)

- http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue when converting my HTML files to PHP, there was no intellisense available at all - not even for the HTML portions. To fix this, R-click the PHP file in Solution Explorer and select Open With... , then select "HTML Editor" and "Set as Default". It won't give PHP support, but it brought back HTML intellisense for me.