# Visual Studio project type for PHP projects

Tags: php, visual-studio

Ok, I feel like this should be obvious but I'm just not seeing things. I am fairly new to the .NET scene so I know it's just my unfamiliarity with the IDE that is giving me the problem.

I want to create a PHP project using **native** Visual Studio 2010 functionality. I figured there would be a generic empty project or something like that but I am not seeing it. I created a blank solution but when I go to add new project all I see are choices for specific project types(C#/VB.net etc). How should I do this? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: PHP is something fundamentally different then .NET, there is no such thing as a .NET project in PHP. You should pick; either use .NET or use PHP.

Comment: If you want to develop PHP, you should use an PHP IDE (such as Aptana (http://www.aptana.com) or PHPStorm (http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) The .NET platform is not for PHP, it's for .NET technologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide PHP templates, compiler support or intellisense.

PHP is not a Microsoft technology, so they do not provide custom tooling for it.

There are third party tools like [VS.PHP](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) that utilize the extensibility features of Visual Studio to offer PHP support in Visual Studio, but there is nothing "native", as you put it.

---

See this related question from 2009 - [Native php support in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911254/native-php-support-in-visual-studio-2010).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have mentioned this in the original post but the whole reason I want to do this in the first place is my boss wants to use the publishing feature of VS for a PHP project. I work at a .NET shop and this is how he wants it to work. Regardless of the fact that VS is not ideal for PHP(I agree totally) he wants this to happen. Is there not a generic sort of project type can use?

Comment: @TheMethod - You could be using a web project - if you set the PHP files as content, they will get published. You will still not get any proper syntax highlighting or other built in support.

Comment: @Oded: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5