# Using Visual Studio 2010 as an editor for non-VS projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, open-source, editor

Is anyone using VS 2010 as an editor for non-VS projects? I recently started a contracting job with an open source shop that has a lot of code in JS and PHP file. My editor of choice is Visual Studio 2010, but VS wants to work with .SLN and .CSPROJ files.

Other editors like Aptana and Zend seem to be happy when I point them at a location on the hard drive, and they root themselves from there without any extra prompting.

What are some tips/tricks for using using VS as a LAMP stack editor?

**[EDIT based on feedback below]:**

I am **NOT** looking for LAMP-stack editor that lets me compile. Rather, I just want to root VS at, say, C:\MyLampProject and then have the IDE show me the directory structure from that location so I can easily open PHP and JS files.

Comment: FWIW the Zeus editor can edit JS and PHP files and it also has a Visual Studio keyboard mapping. So while Zeus is not VS, from the keyboard perspective it should feel like VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

Visual studio is an editor made by Microsoft for use with Microsoft languages, such as C#,  VB.net, C++ and F#. Even though can exist mods on internet (I really dont know anyone) I dont think they will work nicely (intellisense will not work, for example).

Visual studio are not like Eclipse.

Eclipe may work for what you want, but it depends on the language you are going to work with.

**EDIT**

Visual studio will open any files you want, but it cant compile neither understand projects that are not those I mentioned.

**EDIT2**

After writing this post, I found out this:

[Native PHP support in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911254/native-php-support-in-visual-studio-2010)
http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php

Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just to clarify, I'm not looking for something to *compile* code from the LAMP stack. I just need VS to get rooted to, say, c:\MyLampProject and then let me see the directory structure from there so I can easily open files in VS.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because VS really wants to have a CSPROJ and SLN to work the way it was intended to work. There may be ways to achieve what I was asking, but that would be like driving around a sports car while dragging around a one-ton ball and chain. Why would you do that?